# How can I support the Redis sentinel architecture using StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-sentinel

My application uses the `StackExchange.Redis` package and I started using the sentinel architecture in order to support high availability and failures.

I've search the web, trying to find the correct way I should use the `ConnectionMultiplexer` object while using the sentinel architecture and couldn't really find a useful answer.

Some posts say that it doesn't support it yet or partially supports it, some tell you to add all your redis connection addresses to the connection string and some tell you that they provided a custom implementation by subscribing to events.

So, does the `ConnectionMultiplexer` support this kind of architecture? 
If the answer is yes, how should my connection string look like?

Answer (score 4):

You might be looking for this:

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/pull/406

Comment: TL;DR: Sentinel support has been added with [this PR](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/pull/1067). The required configuration for such a connection is documented [here](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration).